# Unable to escape @ sign in perl

Tags: perl, escaping

I am trying to escape the @ sign in perl but I have failed with whatever I tried. I am giving the code below as well as the output. Requesting help to solve the issue.

```
my $p4com = 'p4 print $java_file\@='.$changelist_no;
print $p4com;
my $fileContent = `p4 print $java_file\@=$changelist_no`;
print $fileContent;
```

The code errors out and the command I am trying to run also fails. What I am trying to do is print a perforce file changed in a particular changelist.

Error in output :

```
p4 print //.../smp/configbasetemplate/client/Dummy.java
@=175085sh: line 1: @=175085: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that you're failing to escape the `@`, it's that you have a newline at the end of `$java_file`, so the shell is interpreting the `@=175085` part as a separate command.

To remove the problematic newline, write:

```
chomp $java_file
```